# Time and Date in batch script

Tags: date, batch-file, time

I have this script lying around which creates Foo_Tue0621_185650

```
echo on
for /f "tokens=1,2,3 delims=/- " %%x in ("%date%") do set d=%%x%%y%%z
for /f "tokens=1,2,3 delims=:. " %%x in ("%time%") do set t=%%x%%y%%z
echo zipping...
"C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" a -tzip "D:\Documents\Foo_%d%_%t%.zip" "D:\Documents\Fooo"
echo Done
```

Could someone direct me towards a guide on how this is done. Or explain the script and the `%%x` etc. I have found several topics showing how to pull sub-strings using `set yy=%date:~-4%` etc

But I still wish to understand what I have here.

Comment: `for /?` should answer all of your questions, but [SS64](https://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html) has a more in-depth and better readable description.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need is a single line [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file) command.

The following example uses the built-in `Robocopy.exe` utility to generate a known format date and time string, *(`Foo_yyyyMMdd_hhmmss.zip`)*, instead of using the `WMIC.exe` utility, which will no longer be included in upcoming versions of Windows 11.

```bash
@For /F "Tokens=1-6 Delims=/: " %%G In ('""%SystemRoot%\System32\Robocopy.exe" \: . /NJH /L | "%SystemRoot%\System32\find.exe" " 123""') Do @"%ProgramFiles%\7-Zip\7z.exe" a -tzip "D:\Documents\Foo_%%G%%H%%I_%%J%%K%%L.zip" "D:\Documents\Fooo"
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to extract pertinent data using `wmic`

```
for /f %%y in ('wmic path win32_utctime get /format:list ^| findstr "="') do set "%%y"
for /f %%y in ('wmic path win32_localtime get /format:list ^| findstr "="') do set "%%y"
set /a DateStamp=Year*10000+Month*100+Day
set /a Month+=100&SET /a Hour+=100&SET /a Day+=100&SET /a Minute+=100&SET /a Second+=100
set Month=%Month:~-2%
set Day=%Day:~-2%
set Hour=%Hour:~-2%
set Minute=%Minute:~-2%
set Second=%Second:~-2%
set TimeStamp=%Year%-%Month%-%Day%_%Hour%%Minute%%Second%
echo %TimeStamp%
```

Since `wmic` returns the data in suppressed-leading-0 format, adding `100` to each value, then grabbing the last 2 digits will yield the result in leading-zero format.

Obviously, use either the first or second `for` depending on whether you require UTC or local time/date.

See `for /?` or `set /?` from the prompt for documentation - or thousands of examples on SO

Comment: Thank you. I have already seen such examples. I wanted to know what the script I found was doing.